# jQuery capture CTRL + S and Command + S (Mac)

Tags: jquery, macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, keypress

I know this question was asked serval times here on stackoverflow and I tried some different solutions, but can't find a code that works for me.

I want to capture the keyboard command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on Mac, currently I use this code (with jQuery 2.1.0):

```
jQuery(window).on('keypress', function(event){
    if (!(event.which == 115 && (event.ctrlKey||event.metaKey)) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;

    // my save function

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This Code works fine in:

- Safari: With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Firefox: With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Chrome: **Only** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> works

You will see that the problem is Google Chrome, here I can only capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Has anybody an idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code works for me. I tested it in Chrome (v33) Firefox (v24) and Safari (v6.1.1 ). Both <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> work.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
        // If Control or Command key is pressed and the S key is pressed
        // run save function. 83 is the key code for S.
        if((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.which == 83) {
            // Save Function
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };
    }
);
```

Please note that I am using `keydown` and not `keypress`. In the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) they sate:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official
>   specification, the actual    behavior encountered when using it may
>   differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

I would avoid using it.